# Image Upload is not working in a Laravel Project hosted in a shared server

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have deployed a Laravel project in a shared hosting. I have changed my .env file and copied all files from the public folder to the main directory and deleted the public folder. Now the problem is, whenever I am trying to upload an image, I am getting an internal server error. I suppose the problem is the Image Intervention is not getting the right folder to save the image. I have tried the both ways given below:

```
if ($request->hasfile('admin_pro_pic')) {  
    $image = $request->file('admin_pro_pic');
    $filename  = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $location = public_path('/images/admin/' . $filename);
    Image::make($image)->resize(950, 700)->save($location);
    $admin->admin_pro_pic = $filename;               
}
```

and

```
if ($request->hasfile('admin_pro_pic')) {  
    $image = $request->file('admin_pro_pic');
    $filename  = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $location = '/images/admin/' . $filename;
    Image::make($image)->resize(950, 700)->save($location);
    $admin->admin_pro_pic = $filename;               
}
```

But None of these is working. Any possible Solution?

Comment: I have changed public path to base path and have to install php fileinfo to get Intervention image working on Live. Thanks all for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use laravel `base_path` function, so your code will look like this

```
if ($request->hasfile('admin_pro_pic')) {  
    $image = $request->file('admin_pro_pic');
    $filename  = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $location = base_path().'/images/admin/' . $filename;
    Image::make($image)->resize(950, 700)->save($location);
    $admin->admin_pro_pic = $filename;               
}
```

**Answer Update**

Issue was fileinfo extension  missing or disbaled.

Comment: Do you have write permissions with your images folder ?

Comment: I have permission 0755

Comment: Can you show me your error log ? or exact exception you are getting ?

Comment: Whoops, looks like something went wrong. I am getting this when I am trying to upload the image. And nothing in the error log

Comment: Most probably the issue is with your .env file, If you want laravel to display the error for you rather than generic message 'Whoops' message, copy the .env.example to .env. it will then show detailed error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165214/discussion-between-zahid-hasan-emon-and-faraz-irfan).

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
use Storage;
use File;
if(!empty($request->file('admin_pro_pic')))
    {
        $file = $request->file('admin_pro_pic') ;
        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName() ;
        $destinationPath = public_path().'/images/' ;
        $file->move($destinationPath,$fileName);
       
        $admin->image=$fileName;
    }
```

Create **imges** inside public directory.

Answer (score 0):

I am handling it like this:

```
// check for defined upload folder inside .env file, otherwise use 'public'
$publicUploadDir = env('UPLOAD_PUBLIC', 'public/');
// get file from request
$image = $request->file('admin_pro_pic');
// hasing is not necessary, but recommended
$new['path'] = hash('sha256', time());
$new['folder] = 'images/admin/';
$new['extension'] = $file->extension();
// store uploaded file and retrieve path
$image->storeAs($publicUploadDir, implode($new, '.'));
```